# Evitar duplicação em MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js

É possível evitar duplicações em `mysql` ? Eu tive a procurar e nada se encaixa no meu caso, sempre que eu tento duplica na mesma.

**Eu estou tentando importar isto na tabela:**
`INSERT INTO profiles (id, rep, gems, plevel) VALUES (id, 0, 100, 1)`

Comment: Você deseja evitar que tenha inserts com valores iguais?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para evitar a duplicação, você deve definir a chave que não quer que seja duplicada como `PRIMARY KEY`. Ou seja, se não quer dois id's repetidos, a coluna `id` deve ser uma `PRIMARY KEY`.
Dessa forma, quando tentar inserir um registro com o mesmo ID, o MySQL vai retornar o erro `DUPLICATE ENTRY '0' FOR KEY 'id'`.

Answer (score 1):

Tente colocar o `ID` como chave primária, e os demais valores que você não deseja que exista repetido utilize o atributo `unique`.

Exemplo de criação de tabela com campo `Unique`:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    UNIQUE (ID)
);
```

Exemplo de alteração da estrutura da tabela para que seja `unique`:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD UNIQUE (ID);
```

Remover `Unique`:

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
DROP INDEX UC_Person;
```

Fonte: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp